# Angular Service not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using version 1.2.2 of AngularJS and MVC 5 and I am having a problem getting my service code from getting executed.

Here are my links in my _Layout.cshtml file

```
div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Albums", "Index", "Album")</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My module looks like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Home',
            {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'
            })
        .when('/Album',
            {
                controller: 'AlbumController',
                templateUrl: '/View/Album/Index.cshtml'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
});
```

My `AlbumController` looks like this

```
app.controller('AlbumController', function ($scope, albumService) {

    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.albums = albumService.getAlbums();
    }
});
```

My `albumService` looks like this

```
app.service('albumService', function () {
    this.getAlbums = function () {
        return albums;
    };

    var albums = [
        {
            id: 1, Name: 'Foo', AlbumNumber: 1,
            Songs: [
                { Id: 1, Name: 'Bar', AlbumId: 1, TrackNumber: 1 }
            ]
        }
    ];
});
```

My `View/Album/Index.cshtml` looks like this:

{{album.Name}}

The problem is that the album name is not displayed on the page.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My ng-app directive is in my _Layout.cshtml file.

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: Where is your ng-app directive?

Comment: Am about to update the text with that.

Comment: If you view source do you see that the angular scripts are being included? Since you don't have them in your snippets above, it's not clear.

Comment: Also, view network traffic. Make sure angular and angular-route are being pulled down.

Comment: They do get pulled down.

Comment: I'm out of ideas off the top of my head, if you want to post the entire solution somewhere that I can pull it from, I'd be happy to take a stab at it.

Comment: Where do I send you a link to it?

Comment: Perhaps you can send me an email (address in profile) and I'll send you a link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43782/discussion-between-sachin-kainth-and-billb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

albums is an array . Check {{albums[0].Name}}.

Comment: Again, nothing is printed.

Answer (score -1):

Use app.factory rather than app.service

So

```
app.factory('albumService', function(){

   return albuns;
});
```

Comment: Explain your answer and don't sign it with 'Thanks' or anything. Thanks.